# Will the moisture content in steam turbine power plant decrease the work expansion of the turbine?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

In a steam turbine power plant. If the moisture content is increased during the expansion of turbine stages. Will Wturbine decrease because of some of the steam has been converted from gas to water?

Comment: @Bob D can you help please.

Comment: Seems to me the steam ending back at liquid means you've gotten pretty much all the available energy out of it, no?

Comment: If you have a pressure-enthalpy diagram, follow an isentrope down from a superheated state at high pressures to lower pressures and see how the rate of change of enthalpy with respect to pressure changes once part of the steam crosses over into the saturated region.

Comment: @ChetMiller Can you provide a link to a ph diagram that includes lines of constant entropy? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: @BobD  Moran et al has one for R410A in the appendices.  I haven't checked, but I'm sure Perry's Handbook has one for water.  As best I can tell, there is not a drastic change in slope when the constant entropy line enters the saturation region.  I pasted a pH diagram for water into an answer.

Comment: Steam turbine "buckets" don't like liquid water impingement.  Due to that, superheated steam is sent through them to avoid condensation between turbine stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure enthalpyy diagram for water:

[image]

Note that there is no drastic change in the slope of the isentropes when they enter the saturation region.

Comment: Could you please explain the significance of any change in slope of the isentrope entering the saturation region to the relationship between the turbine work and moisture content at the turbine output.

Comment: @bobd The work done by the turbine is equal to the change in enthalpy.  So a change in slope of the isentrope is an indication of a change in the rate of doing rate with respect to pressure change.

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking about an isentropic turbine that operates between the same two pressures where in the first case saturated vapor enters the turbine and in the second case superheated steam enters the turbine. Based on the T-S diagram,  for the first case the quality of the exiting steam is lower than the quality for the second case .  When I compute the work done (for an example involving a turbine operating between 1 and 0.1 MPa) I get more work done for the second case than the first.

Comment: So at least in this example more work is done for a lower moisture content, at least during a part of the expansion.

Comment: @BobD How would an ideal gas do if it started out at higher temperature for the same pressure change?

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. What does an ideal gas have to do with the example I gave?

Comment: @bobd I am just wondering how much of the effect you noted is just due to starting out at a higher temperature.

Comment: And I was proposing to use an ideal gas as an example to help quantify that.

Comment: I acknowledge that in my example, in which I compared 180 C saturated vapor vs 350 C superheated steam entering the turbine operating between 1 and 0.1 Mpa, the reason the superheated steam produced more work is primarily due to the higher temperature. The increase in input enthalpy is greater than the increase in exiting enthalpy resulting in more work of about 90 kJ/kg or a 31% increase.

Comment: But more work would also be obtatained with no increase in temperature, though admittedly not a lot. For example, if one compares a wet steam input  of 0.7 quality at 180 C (which I would assume would never apply to a steam turbine) to saturated vapor input  at 180 C, the latter would also result in an inrease in work of about 25 kJ, or a 9% increase.

Comment: In any case, I didn’t mean to imply that a decrease in moisture content is the cause of more work (or vise-versa), only that such a decrease is associated with more work due to the corresponding required increase in input enthalpy for an isentropic turbine. Thanks for the input.